# How to filter / loop through a nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, nested

I have an array like this

```js
let names = [
    {name:"Haruhiro", alias:["Haru", "Hal"]},
    {name:"John", alias:["Jon"]},
    {name:"Samantha", alias:["Sam"]},
]
```

And I need to filter the items of it based on what the user types in.

```
let output = names.filter((e) => e.name === userInput);
```

This works well with only names, but I couldn't do it so that it fill check for both name and possible alias, since it can have as many alias as it wants I need to loop throuh it but I'm already in a sort of loop while I'm in the filter. I tried something like

```
let output = names.filter((e) => e.name === userInput || e.alias.filter((a) => a === userInput));
```

but it wouldn't work. So There's an array in an array that I'm looping through which I need to loop through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over the nested array with `some` which returns `true/false`, instead of `filter` which returns an array of elements(always `true`).

```js
let names = [
  {name:"Haruhiro", alias:["Haru", "Hal"]},
  {name:"John", alias:["Jon"]},
  {name:"Samantha", alias:["Sam"]},
];

const result = names.filter(person => person.name === "no" || person.alias.some(alias => alias === 'Hal'));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn't it stop after finding 1 that fits "Hal". I need to filter out every "Hal" if there were to be multiple

Comment: oh no I think I get it, it could work. It should work. I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

Since your allias arrray you can use the [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method on it to see if it has the value in it you want to check for so your code will be this:

```js
let names = [{
    name: "Haruhiro",
    alias: ["Haru", "Hal"]
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    alias: ["Jon", "Hal"]
  },
  {
    name: "Samantha",
    alias: ["Sam"]
  },
]
let userInput = 'Hal'

let output = names.filter((e) => e.name === userInput || e.alias.includes(userInput));
console.log(output)
```